# SBS 2011 Folder Redirection not working after migration

Tags: group-policy, windows-sbs-2011, folder-redirection

I followed the  [Migrate SBS 2008 to SBS 2011 guide](http://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=19219) which worked well.  However **RedirectedFolders** haven't migrated over properly - Windows 7 workstations are still actively connecting to the old RedirectedFolders shared folder on an old file server, as well as the new RedirectedFolders shared folder on the new SBS server.

Can someone please assist?

Group Policies were updated under User Configuration -> Policies -> Windows Settings -> Folder Redirection, using the following settings for required folders.

[image: Folder Redirection, Desktop Properties]

[image: Folder Redirection, Desktop Properties]

Below is a screenshot of one user's two RedirectedFolders, with the new server on the right.  As you can see the old server's RedirectedFolders are being updated (Desktop, My Docs etc), but the new server isn't.

[image: RedirectedFolders on old server and new server]

On the Windows 7 workstations, event logs are seen: ID 502 "Failed to apply policy and redirect folder "Desktop" to "\New-Server\RedirectedFolders\User\Desktop". Redirection options=0x80001021.".

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running `gpupdate /force` in an administrative command prompt on the win7 machines?